# От какого слова образовано "преткновение"?

Tags: словообразование

От какого слова образовано "преткновение"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 4):

**Пре/тк/ну/ть/ся – пре/тк/н/ов/ени/е.**

Суффиксальный способ, при образовании используется сложный формант ОВ+ЕНИ, усечение суффикса НУ в основе до Н.

Сравнить: при/кос/ну/ть/ся – при/кос/н/ов/ени/е.

Comment: Разве это ответ на вопрос "от какого слова..."?

Comment: Это ответ на вопрос, как образовалось отглагольное существительное "преткновение". Обычно такие существительные   обозначают название действия (сравнить: прикоснуться - прикосновение, затрудняться - затруднение)).  Но слово "преткновение" в современном языке используется только устойчивом сочетании  "камень преткновения" (препятствие, затруднение в каком-л. деле). Иными словами,  "причина затруднения".

Answer (score 3):

От глагола *преткнуться* (или *претыкать(ся)*), который значит "споткнуться" и употребляется главным образом в книжной речи, путем добавления группы морфем *-новение* (н/ов/ениj/э). (Ср. также: иссякнуть, иссяк-новение, отдохнуть, отдох-новение.)

Comment: А каким способом?

Comment: @Lirimiri суффиксальным (с добавлением -(н)овение к глагольной основе). Так образуются некоторые другие книжные слова, например иссякнуть, иссяк-новение, отдохнуть, отдох-новение.